# Python Plot, delete just the Label from the Legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I just want to delete the Label from the Legend:

example (i just copy pasted the plot from an other stackoverflow problem)[Plot example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot)

[image]

The question is, is there a way to delete the color Labels in the legend?

So that I'll just see "first" , "second" , "third" without the blue,green,red color label.

My problem is, i just want to use 1 Value in the Legend ( float ) and i dont want to have a label. 
The Value should be outside of the plot like in this example.
I use the Legend with this code:

```
PC= np.pearsonr(x,y)
plt.scatter(x,y,color="#3F5D7D",label='PK:  %.3f'%(PC[0]))
plt.legend(prop={'size':12},bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1.1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title seems a little misleading as it states you want to delete the Label (*text part*) from the Legend, however the text of your question states you want to just see the text without the red, green and blue (*Legend Key*).

If you want to keep the Label(text), you can substitute the default key for a blank one by creating an empty rectangle as below. (creating a proxy artist for the legend)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import random
import scipy.stats as ss

pop = range(100)
x = random.sample(pop, 10)
y = random.sample(pop, 10)
PC = ss.pearsonr(x, y)
plt.scatter(x,y,color="#3F5D7D")
blank = matplotlib.patches.Rectangle((0,0), 0, 0, fill=False, edgecolor='none', visible=False)
plt.legend([blank], ['PK:  %.3f'%(PC[0])], prop={'size':12},bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1.1))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove one label from an existing plot you can try this:

```
label_to_remove='remove_me'
h,l=ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

idx_keep=[k[0] for k in enumerate(l) if l[k[0]] != label_to_remove]

handles=[]
labels=[]

for i in idx_keep:
    handles.append(h[i])
    labels.append(l[i])
print(handles, labels)
ax.legend(handles, labels, loc='upper right')
```